# Upstream location changed to HTTPS after redirect

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I use Nginx as a reverse proxy to serve an internal HTTP application over a HTTPS connection.
But I hae some problems with redirection.

This is my setup:

```
location / {
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
   proxy_pass      http://172.16.88.208;
   proxy_intercept_errors on;
   error_page 302 = @handle_redirects;
}

location @handle_redirects {
   resolver 8.8.8.8;
   set $orig_loc $upstream_http_location;
   proxy_pass $orig_loc;
}
```

At first, I tried it without setting the resolver to 8.8.8.8 but encountered this error (while a 502 was displayed to the client):

> *1 no resolver defined to resolve xxx.xxxx.com while sending to client, client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

After setting the resolver I'm getting closer, but not quite. Still a 502 and this error:

> *6 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream,
> upstream: "https://172.16.88.208:443/login"

Well, that makes perfect sense, because the application is hosted at http://, not https://

I specify this in the code above:

> set $orig_loc $upstream_http_location;

Why is the $upstream_http_location redirected to a https page?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I wanted to do a little hack and tried "proxy_pass http://172.16.88.208/" (note the last slash indicating that the path should be appended). But apparently setting a URL in a named location is forbidden. So I'm out of luck.

Comment: Do you want to redirect between the client and Nginx, or between Nginx and upstream server?

Comment: quick question. why do you need to intercept the redirect from your backend. wouldn’t be a simple reverse proxy (https to http) do the trick?